# How to look for escaped characters in javascript (i.e \| )

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, bootstrap-multiselect

So I am using Bootstrap Multiselect with datatables and trying to do a multiselect search per column. It will search just fine for text if it's the only one selected but it needs to select for text that is joined on the | character. I have to pass the values through the .escapeRegex method but when I do that after I have joined on the | function the it shows up as \| and it won't search.

Another approach I was thinking about trying was iterating through test and joining on , instead of | and replacing the last , with | after I feed it through escape regex.

Any help will be appreciated!

here is the javascript:

```js
select = $('<select class="form-control" multiple="multiple" id="' + currHeaderName + '\"><option value=""></option></select>')
  .appendTo($(column.header())).on('change', function() {

    var test;
    if ($(this).val() == null) {
      test = $(this).val();
    } else {
      test = $(this).val().join("|");
    }

    if (test.indexOf('(' > -1)) {
      val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(test);

      column.search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false).draw();
    } else {

      column.search(test.replace('\|/g', '|'), true, false).draw();
    }

  });

column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
  select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>');
});

$('#' + currHeaderName).multiselect({
  nonSelectedText: 'Select a Filter...',
  includeSelectAllOption: true
});
```

Comment: use /\|/g, could needed to escaped this special character?

Comment: `.replace('/|/g', '|')` What are you trying to do?

Comment: hi @Rajesh I update, I meant to update that to \|

Comment: Note `'\|/g'` is enclosed inside quotes, so it is string and not regex